# Вопрос о регистрации на сайте

Tags: php

Как сделать подтверждения по email и восстановления пароля по нему?
То есть на емаил приходит ссылка и при клике по этой ссылке открывается страница с вводом нового пароля. 
Как генерировать эту ссылку что бы привязать к пользователю и она кидала на наш сайт не могу этого понять подскажите

Comment: Первые три ссылки точно помогут Вам понять схему: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+email&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruUA810UA810&oq=rfr+cltkfnm+gjlndth%3Bltybt+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8613j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм примерно следующй. В момент, когда пользователь запросил восстановление пароля, Вы:

1. Генерируете рандомный уникальный токен (хэш).
2. Складываете этот токен в БД с привязкой к юзеру.
3. Отправляете юзеру на мыло ссылку вида `http://example.com/pwd?token=<сгенерированный_токен>`
4. Когда юзер по этой ссылке возвращается на Ваш сайт, сопоставляете токены и если ОК то показываете форму восстановления пароля.

Естественно, этот алгоритм максимально прост, он не претендует ни на изысканность, ни на безопасность, и вообще ни на что, это просто примр для понимания. Удачи.

Comment: Можно токен генерировать исходя из уникальных данных юзера (id,мыло, etc.) тогда не придётся хранить токен в БД. Единственный минус - хеш будет всегда одинаковый.

Comment: @StackOverflow ну я один из подходов описал. Саму алгоритмику процесса. Дальше сам поймёт. К тому-же если токен генерить таким способом, то зачастую достаточно увидеть исходники движка чтобы понять как это сделано и получить доступ к любому аккаунту. Тот-же WordPres например, смотри не хочу, да и вообще как бы немало открытых движков.